# Rendering is Cached

Tags: caching, html-caching

I am using Sitecore 9.3 and I have a `.cshtml` updated but the update is not reflected on CD server although the physical file is updated.

I do iisreset and publish for the site to clear any cache but this didn't solve the issue as well.

Also, I tried to change the file name and change it in rendering but it didn't solve the issue also.

Any advise?

Comment: Can you please provide more info about the cshtml, whether you applied rendering cache etc and also make sure that the rendering has been published to the target database

Comment: The rendering is published and the cshtml is as below no caching is applied:

    <div class="col-12 p-0">
        @if (Model.Item != null)
        {
            foreach (BaseVariantField variantField in Model.VariantFields)
            {
                @Html.RenderingVariants().RenderVariant(variantField, Model.Item, Model.RenderingWebEditingParams, Model)
            }
        }
    </div>

Comment: Have you applied sitecore cache such as vary by data etc on the rendering properties? Also make sure that the correct rendering and it’s associated cshtml has been configured on the item

Comment: No Caching is applied and the html is associated with the current rendering

Comment: Did you check the actual location where the cshtml is placed, Sometimes the latest file gets copied to wrong location in case of manual deployment

Comment: Perhaps you are precompiling your views and thus any change to the physical file will not have an effect unless you have `UsePhysicalViewsIfNewer` set to true. https://kamsar.net/index.php/2016/09/Precompiled-Views-with-Sitecore-8-2/

Answer (score 4):

There may be many reasons.

1. If you have multiple CD servers and .cshtml file deployed only one server correctly.
2. File location is not correct, you can cross check if file location is correct by navigating rendering path in sitecore tree.
3. Remove caching on rendering level.